# Cannot encode vp9 video with alpha to ivf container

Tags: ffmpeg, vp9

I'm trying to convert a vp8/webm video with transparency to vp9 and ivf container. I can encode the video to vp9 into webm container with the following command which correctly produces a vp9 video with transparency:

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx -i dancer1.webm -c:v libvpx-vp9 dancer_vp9.webm
```

So basically forcing `libvpx` encoders instead of ffmpeg native ones to support alpha.

However if I try to use ivf container instead of webm the resulting video does not have transparency:

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx -i dancer1.webm -c:v libvpx-vp9 dancer_vp9.ivf
```

Does not have transparency when played with VLC, when converting frames to PNG using ffmpeg (`ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i dancer_vp9.ivf -vf "select=eq(n\,0)" frame.png`) and when played in Chrome (using webcodecs API). Does ivf not support alpha channel somehow or am I doing something wrong?

I also tried copying the stream with alpha from webm container to ivf (`ffmpeg -i dancer1_vp9.webm -c copy dancer1_vp9_copy.ivf`) which produces the same result, no transparency.

Curiously if I force or don't force libvpx decoder (which is required to support transparency, ffmpeg native one seems to just discard the alpha channel) when reading vp8/vp9 webm video it produces the same result when outputting to ivf container, while when outputting to webm container the resulting video has alpha when using `libvpx` decoder and not when using native ffmepg decoder.

ffprobe output of created ivf file:

```
ffprobe version 5.0.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.0.1_3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
Input #0, ivf, from 'dancer_vp9.ivf':
  Duration: 00:01:02.87, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 249 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: vp9 (Profile 0) (VP90 / 0x30395056), yuv420p(tv), 640x360, 30 tbr, 30 tbn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alpha component is emitted separately by vpx encoders and stored adjacent to the main packet in the container. Only Matroska / WebM support writing this side data.